# scrapy spider log not written to log file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider class deriving from `BaseSpider`. I call `self.log` but nothing gets written to the logfile. I configure the logfile on the command-line `LOG_FILE` and `LOG_LEVEL` but the spider log output is not written to that file. How do I get the spider logs to be written to the normal log file?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your callback is getting called?

Because having this simple spider in a file `example.py`:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('************* my log ***********')
```

And running it with `scrapy runspider example.py --set LOG_FILE=logfile`, this is the file content:

```
2013-09-30 22:55:12-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: mybot)
2013-09-30 22:55:12-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: MybotPipeline
2013-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [example] INFO: Spider opened
2013-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [example] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [example] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/> (referer: None)
2013-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [example] DEBUG: ************* my log ***********
2013-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [example] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [example] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 221,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 1611,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 1, 2, 55, 13, 315807),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 1, 2, 55, 12, 991150)}
2013-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [example] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Try adding a failure to your callback to make sure is getting called. Something simple like `raise Exception`. If you don't get an exception when running it, then your callback is not getting called.

Comment: I'm certain my callback is being called (As I'm getting results and print statements write to stdout). None of the `self.log` calls however write to the log file.

Comment: It appears the log is to the DEBUG level by default and that is why I don't see the output (I'm only writing INFO+ levels).